# Android device is hardware encrypted or not? Programmatically

Tags: android, encryption, hardware

How to check whether the Android device is hardware encrypted or not? Programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341684/find-out-whether-the-device-is-full-disk-encrypted-and-what-encryption-was-used

Comment: What do you mean by 'hardware encrypted'? Current (publicly available) Android devices don't support hardware crypto at all.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to the linked [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341684/find-out-whether-the-device-is-full-disk-encrypted-and-what-encryption-was-used) question

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private boolean isEncrypted(Context context) {
        DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            int status = devicePolicyManager.getStorageEncryptionStatus();
            if (DevicePolicyManager.ENCRYPTION_STATUS_ACTIVE == status) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```